# Extending ASP.NET Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, ef-code-first

I want to implement a one-to-many relation in my DB with the users-table in ASP.NET MVC3.
*i.e. One user has many cars.* 
And also I want to extend the default user-model (MembershipUser ??) with many other fields.
i.e.:

```
public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars;
public virtual decimal? Balance;
public virtual bool isGreatUser;
...
```

What is the best (right) way to do this? How can I implement this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer from Daryl...about the other part:

> And also I want to extend the default user-model (MembershipUser ??)
>   with many other fields.

There are two ways you can accomplish this:

- Custom profiles trough using [ProfileProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profileprovider.aspx) class
- [Custom membership user](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-membership-user/)

In either case you need to inherit from some class(ProfileProvider or MebershipUser) and extend them with your data.

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm nice:

Don't try to hook in MembershipUser in your entity classes. Keep Membership and EntityFramework separate components.

Just have your User class (what you have there is fine, for your 1-M Car relationship). Then when you retrieve your User class, use that to configure Membership.